# Can't rebind key C-z in xemacs

Tags: xemacs

For some reason, "C-z" is mapped to suspend-or-iconify-emacs and I can't seem to get it to rebind to something less annoying.  (I like using ctrl-z for undo, but doing nothing would at least be better than suspending every time I accidentally hit the key)

I've tried doing it interactively: 
`M-x global-set-key`, then `Set key C-z to command: undo`.
`M-x describe-key-briefly` gives me `C-z runs the command suspend-or-iconify-emacs`

I've tried going to the scratch buffer and evaluating:
`(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)` and `(global-set-key "\C-z" 'undo)`, and it is of course in my .xemacs/init.el file.

Nothing seems to actually rebind the key.

This is happening on XEmacs 21.5, in Fundamental mode.  Any ideas on how to troubleshoot this?

edit:  Ok here is a hack that gets around the problem by redefining the suspend function to undo:

`(defun suspend-or-iconify-emacs () (interactive) (undo))`

I can't actually suspend emacs anymore, but that's actually ok with me.

Comment: Please remove the tag "emacs" and add the tag "xemacs" to your question. Thx.

Comment: Deniz, I would prefer to understand and solve the problem with xemacs as I am not the only user of this system.

Answer (score 3):

Try evaluating this:

```
(define-key global-window-system-map [(control z)] 'undo)
```

(assuming that you aren't running XEmacs in tty-mode, but I guess you are not, if you want to iconify :-))

I used C-h b to find out what *-map to modify.

Answer (score 3):

I have the following code in my .emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'eshell)
```

It will start an eshell, and it works.

The C-z combination is pretty standard on Unix/Linux, if you're working in a terminal with e.g. vi, lynx or mutt and presses C-z the program will suspend and you will be back in the shell. Issuing the 'fg' command will pop the program back again. As Emacs has its own shell, I like spawning that when pressing C-z in Emacs.

You can also add the following hook, that will remap C-z in the eshell. That way pressing C-z in the eshell with get you back to the buffer you were editing.

```
(add-hook 'eshell-mode-hook
  (lambda ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'bury-buffer)))
```

Comment: Didn't even realize that I missed this until I had it back. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Put that **at the end** of your .xemacs/init.el :

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-z") 'undo)
```

Or maybe you have a misconfigured keyboard or operating system.

Do <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>k</kbd> <kbd>C-z</kbd> to see if xemacs really receives a <kbd>C-z</kbd> key.

Comment: `M-x describe-key-briefly` is basically a short version of C-h k.

Comment: Did you try your own suggestion? It doesn't work for me, I think due to C-z not being defined in global-map, but in global-window-system-map.

Comment: That's why you should try, I've not said that C-z works on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with C-f. I wanted it to map to isearch-forward, but instead it kept moving one character forward.

I finally solved my problem by adding

```
(global-unset-key [?\C-f])
(global-set-key [?\C-f] 'isearch-forward)
```

Apparently the issue is that C-f (and C-z) is a "real" key, that is, it's something that a terminal recognizes (it's ASCII 0x06, 0x1a for C-z), so you need the "?\" in front of "C-f".

This is the only thing I got to work.

HTH

(EDIT: I should note that I use emacs, not xemacs)

Comment: Also, if all you want is C-z mapped to undo, you might try cua-mode.